# Why does my context not update state as expected?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

The imageList is empty even though I have used this.context.setImageList to update the state to get the data from the API. I am confused why the state just didn't update. I have been spending a lot of time on this and haven't found the root cause. I'd appreciate if you can guide me through it. Thank you!

- Create context and attach it in the Provider

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const ImageListContext = React.createContext({
  imageList: [],
  error: null,
  loading: true,
  setError: () => {},
  clearError: () => {},
  setImageList: () => {},
})
export default ImageListContext

export class ImageListProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    imageList: [],
    error: null,
  };
  setImageList = imageList => {
    this.setState({imageList})
  }

  setError = error => {
    console.error(error)
    this.setState({ error })
  }

  clearError = () => {
    this.setState({ error: null })
  }

  render() {
    const value = {
      imageList: this.state.imageList,
      error: this.state.error,
      setError: this.setError,
      clearError: this.clearError,
      setImageList: this.setImageList,
    }
    return (
      <div>
      {this.loading ? <div>Loading Images...</div> :
      <ImageListContext.Provider value={value}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ImageListContext.Provider>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

- Use Context to update imageList array with the data from API and get the data out of the array to display it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ImageApiService from '../../services/image-api-service'
import { Section } from '../../components/Utils/Utils'
import ImageListItem from '../../components/ImageListItem/ImageListItem'
import './ImageListPage.css'
import ImageListContext from '../../contexts/ImageListContext'

export default class ImageListPage extends Component {
  static contextType = ImageListContext;
  componentDidMount() {
   //this calls the image API to get all images!
    ImageApiService.getImages()
    .then(resJson => this.context.setImageList(resJson))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))

  }

  setError = error => {
    console.error(error)
    this.setState({ error })
  }

  clearError = () => {
    this.setState({ error: null })
  }

  renderImages() {
    const { imageList=[] } = this.context;
   console.log(imageList)
    return imageList.map(image =>
      <ImageListItem
        key={image.id}
        image={image}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (

        <Section list className='ImageListPage'>
        {this.context.error
          ? <p className='red'>There was an error, try again</p>
          : this.renderImages()}
      </Section>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you inject `ImageListContext.Provider`? it is not used in sample above;

Comment: I did : <ImageListContext.Provider value={value}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ImageListContext.Provider>

Comment: yes, right, sorry for missing that